# How to split numbers individually in python from a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This question is somewhat the same about others but different on what I'm trying to interpret as i'm also new to python.

suppose that i have sample.txt:

```
123
456

321
780
```

both are separated by white space. but i wanted them to look like:

```
>> goal = '123456'
>> start = '456312'
```

and my start up code somehow looks like:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    out = f.read().split()
    print map(int, out)
```

which results to:

```
>> [123, 456, 456, 123]
```

which is different from what I''m trying to exert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is loop through the file line by line, and if the line is empty then start a new string in the result list, otherwise append the line to the last element of the result list:

```
lst = ['']

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:

    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if len(line) == 0:
            lst.append('')
        else:
            lst[-1] += line

lst
# ['123456', '321780']
```

Comment: Question sir, is it still considered list if i print lst[0] which outputs >>123456 ?

Comment: `lst[0]` gives back the first element in the list, which is a string in this case, it doesn't change `lst`.

Comment: But are they still list because of lst? Can I still make conditions number by number?

Comment: `lst[0]` is a string which is also a list/iterable except that it is immutable, so you can iterate through them like `for n in lst[0]` if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Exactly sir, because this code is gonna be my startup with 8 puzzle solver. Converting the numbers makes it easier for me to condition it if its solvable or not, then on with heuristics and A* algo. Can split also possible in attaining the same result?

Comment: `'r'` when opening a file is redundant, since that's the default

Answer (score -1):

Splint on \n\n. (If this isn't exactly what you need, then modify to suit!)

```
>>> inp = '123\n456\n\n321\n780\n'
>>> [int(num.replace('\n', '')) for num in inp.split('\n\n')]
[123456, 321780]
```

Comment: Why's the down vote? This answer seems more efficient than the other one.